# Image processing for screen printing pre-press in Python

Tags: python, image-processing

What is the math/algorithm involved in extracting a specific hue of color out an rgb image? Trying to figure out what needs to be done to an image to separate into a given number of channels for printing. Trying to do this in Python, and I can easyly get the RGB channels, or CMYK ones using Pillow or OpenCV, but the requirement is to split into 5 or 6 channels, each to be printed on a specific hue (PMS color) that is not the standard CMYK inks, like is being done in Separation Studio (an image processing software for screen printing).

I am expecting to have the color data for the requested number of channels, each defined to be a specific PMS color, and generate an new file with all this color channels.
It is pretty straight forward for me to extract the RGB or CMYK channels , but for the life of me I can't figure out how to approach this problem. Probably because I do not understand how the color representation in the image file will look like. My biggest problem is understanding what happened when  I need to select a color matching RGB(50,50,50) for example ,and a pixel has values RGB(125,70,200), do I substrac the values for each channel, does the pixel then has values RGB(75,20,150) and can start over to extract the next color?

Comment: I think this question may be better asked on a different forum.  Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Basically you're asking how one of the standard colorspaces maps to the colorspace of your PMS.  No idea, but you could make a test image with various colors and then use your existing software to convert it to the 5 or 6 channel colorspace you want.  Then by inspecting the values atttempt to figure out what operation it is performing.